# Fourier Transform of a Response Function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, fourier-transform

I have a response function of the form $\chi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'};t,t')$ at hand. Now, the function is time-invariant so I can write it as $\chi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'};t-t')$ right off the bat. After performing Fourier transform on $t-t'$, I've arrived at $\chi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'},\omega)$ where $\omega$ is the transformation variable of $t-t'$. 

Here's the deal - if the system were translational invariant, I could have written $\chi(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'},\omega)$ and computed the transformation as $\chi(\mathbf{q};\omega)$  
 My question is: if the system under study is not translational invariant; I mean if I can't write $\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'}$ as $\mathbf{r-r'}$ then can I perform Fourier on $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r'}$ individually? and how would the transformed function look like?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Start with computing Fourier of $\chi$ on $t$ and $t'$ and compare to the result you got from $t-t'$

Comment: You can of course, but it wouldn't have all the interpretations that it usually has

Comment: The transformed function will look like $\chi(\mathbf{q}, \mathbf{q'}; \omega)$, i.e., it will be non-diagonal in reciprocal space. If you want to interpret it, you can rewrite it in the form $\chi(\mathbf{k}, \mathbf{k} + \mathbf{q}; \omega)$, making it a function of momentum $\mathbf{k}$ and of momentum transfer $\mathbf{q}$.